# ExtJS - embeding jsp page with extjs grid inside tab

Tags: jsp, extjs, extjs4

Earlier my application was using frames where a jsp page used extjs grid to display data. Now I am trying to remove the frames and use the extjs tab for display. I am able to include the jsp page inside a tab using 
**autoLoad:{url:"test.jsp"}** inside tab. But my problem is the extjs grid is not getting displayed. While searching I just found out by defining 
**autoLoad:{url:"test.jsp", scripts:true}** it activate the scripts inside the jsp page. But on running my application it displays **ext is undefined** . I dont know how it is coming since I have included the ext-all script inside my jsp file. Please help me to know whether the approach is correct or what shall I do to get grid displayed while working with extjs tab.

**MainPage**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
 Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
 height:300,
   items: [
        {
            title: 'eRAM summary',
            autoLoad: {url: 'test1.jsp',scripts:true},
            closable:true
        }
    ],
    renderTo : document.body
});
```

**test.jsp** contains grid as

```
<script>
function getRandomDate() {
    var from = new Date(1900, 0, 1).getTime();
    var to = new Date().getTime();
    return new Date(from + Math.random() * (to - from));
}
function createFakeData(count) {
        var firstNames   = ['Ed', 'Tommy', 'Aaron', 'Abe'];
        var lastNames    = ['Spencer', 'Maintz', 'Conran', 'Elias'];

        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
            var dob = getRandomDate();           
            var firstNameId = Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length);
            var lastNameId  = Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length);
            var name        = Ext.String.format("{0} {1}", firstNames[firstNameId], lastNames[lastNameId]);

            data.push([name, dob]);
        }
        return data;
    }
Ext.onReady(function(){   
     Ext.define('Person',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'Name', 'dob'
        ]
    });

// create the Data Store
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Person',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
            data: createFakeData(10),
            reader: {
                type: 'array'
            }
    }
});
// create the grid
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {text: "Name", width:120, dataIndex: 'Name'},
        {text: "dob", width: 380, dataIndex: 'dob'}
    ],
    renderTo:'example-grid',
    width: 500,
    height: 280
    });    
});
</script>
```

This is the example with which I am trying to embed in my application

Comment: Please show us some code . see [ask]

Comment: Hi @SanKrish I have included the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use

```
   <c:url>
```

while including ext-all.js?

like this

```
<head>
   <link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/ext-all.css' />" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="<c:url value='/extjs/ext-debug.js' />" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<c:url value='/resources/css/ext-all.css' />app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: This could rather be an comment .

Comment: need 50+rep to comment first post. ;(

Comment: Upvoted . please post the complete answer. dont try to post a line and edit it . you can earn reputation through answers that could solve the problem completely . remember suggestions are not complete answers :)

Comment: I tried using <c:url>. The jsp page inside ext tab is not producing the grid.

Comment: Open the browser Dev-tools and check the "Network" tab to see ext-all.js and ext-all.css are loaded. Also check the "Console" tab and (maybe..) post their contents here